# Taking a fixed length string as input in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am trying to input a string in C and print it. My sample code is given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char a[5];
    scanf("%[^\n]a",a);
    printf("%s",a);

}
```

The problem is, I have initially assumed the string length as 5. But if I take a string with length more than 5, it works correctly. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the permitted string length be less than 5?

Comment: "*Why is this happening?*" Undefined behaviour is undefined. "*Shouldn't the permitted string length be*" Permitted by whom? You pass to `scanf()` (implicitly) the address of `a`'s 1st element. You need to explicitly tell it how much it may scan.

Comment: when I declare char a[5], what does this 5 actually mean? @alk

Comment: Also `a` scans a float. To scan a "string" use `s`. If you have defined a `char[5]` that allows a possible "string" of length 5-1=4. C needs 1 `char` to store "string's" `0`-terminator. To tell `scanf()` to only scan 4 `char`s use `%4s`.

Comment: Have you posted the original code here? what is `%a` in `scanf`?

Comment: I have made an edit @army007

Comment: `main()` - implicit `int` has been an error since C99.

Comment: Do not change your question after answers/comments had been given, as the change might render those ununderstandable. That's why I rolled back your edit.

Comment: Bean-counting error.  If you ever, (unless RAM-restricted embedded), declare an input buffer as less than [256], type out 1000 times 'I am a software developer, not an accountant' ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this happening?

"*Undefined behaviour is undefined.*"

> Shouldn't the permitted string length be less than 5?

Permitted by whom? You pass to `scanf()` (implicitly) the address of `a`'s 1st element. You need to explicitly tell it how much it may scan.

Also `a` scans a float. To scan a "string" use `s`.

If you have defined a `char[5]` that allows a possible "string" of length 5-1=4. C needs 1 `char` to store the "string's" `0`-terminator.

To tell `scanf()` to only scan 4 `char`s use `%4s`.

Comment: The square brackets shouldn't be followed by `s`, they are a conversion specifier on their own. The `a` here is taken as a literal character which will fail matching.

Comment: Perhaps `scanf("%4[^\n]",a);` is required. Note `%s` skips spaces. Also worth mention to check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: Even better idea: Never use `scanf`.

Comment: Ey, guys please feel free to edit my answer as you feel is made sense, I already regret to have answered to a scanf-issue... :{

Comment: @melpomene what alternative of `scanf` do you suggest?

Comment: @army007 For user input? `fgets`, because you always want to read a complete line (you can convert it as needed afterwards, e.g. with `strtol` or `sscanf`).